# Filtering a List/.Txt file

Tags: c#, list, filter

I am currently working on a project where I have to load in and filter a txt file, with the filtered txt being saved into a list. At the moment, I have the filters working but they are not maintaining the order of the .txt file.

I understand why this is happening due to the try blocks running one before the other, but I was wondering if there was a way to make my code more efficient and to make it so that the required lines are saved in order that they are read.

I think it may also be better if the pattern variables are saved in one variable, however, I am not sure how they should be formatted as `Regax.Match` does not work when I try to combine both of the strings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace program
{
 internal class Program
{
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var inputFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\olive.txt");

     Filter(inputFile);
  }

  public static void Filter(string fileToBeFiltered)
  {
     var sendList = new List<string>();
     Match m;
     var sendPattern = @"(SEND.+)";
     var getPattern = @"(GET.+)"; //+ "(SEND.+)";


     try
     {
        m = Regex.Match(fileToBeFiltered, getPattern);
        while (m.Success)
        {
           var add = m.Groups[1].ToString();
           sendList.Add(add);
           m = m.NextMatch();
        }
     }
     catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("The matching operation timed out.");
     }

     try
     {
        m = Regex.Match(fileToBeFiltered, sendPattern);
        while (m.Success)
        {
           var add = m.Groups[1].ToString();
           sendList.Add(add);
           m = m.NextMatch();
        }
     }
     catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("The matching operation timed out.");
     }


     foreach (var value in sendList)
        Console.WriteLine(value);
     Console.WriteLine();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: SO is rather for debugging purposes. You may alsor try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for improvements

Answer (score 0):

As you stated your output is not ordered because you search for the send pattern and the get pattern separately. Change your pattern to:

```
var pattern = @"((SEND.+)|(GET.+))";
```

Now leave a single loop and the segments which match the send or get pattern will be added to the list in the order of the file.

Edit: Added another pair of parentheses.